# Program received signal SIGILL Illegal instruction

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb

I'm running an application on a new machine for the first time but getting:

> Program received signal SIGILL, Illegal instruction

and when I do

> x/i $pc

I get:

```
=> 0x7fffe98b8f5b <_ZNSt10_HashtableImSt4pairIKmPN4ICE211t_orderInfoEESaIS5_ENSt8__detail10_Select1stESt8equal_toImESt4hashImENS7_18_Mod_range_hashingENS7_20_Default_ranged_hashENS7_20_Prime_rehash_policyENS7_17_Hashtable_traitsILb0ELb0ELb1EEEEC2Ev+

147>:       vmovss 0x84b4d(%rip),%xmm0        # 0x7fffe993dab0
```

Thought the machine might not have AVX, but checking proc/cpuinfo shows both avx and avx2 architectures available.

The code wasn't compiled on this box and I haven't used this box before. I get the problem when I link statically and dynamically.

Anybody got any tips what it could be? Is it the C++ runtime library version on the machine?

UPDATE: seems this is an AVX512 instruction, which is totally weird. This code is being generated from gcc hashing. There is no AVX512 inline assembly.

Answer (score 0):

If you click on any function in [Intel Intrinsics Guide](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=vmovss&expand=3067) then it would say that `vmovss` requires AVX-512F. AVX and AVX-2 are not enough.

Comment: Okay thanks for this. This is totally bizarre. I have no idea why its generating AVX512 instructons.

Comment: What options were used to compile code? Do they contain `-mavx512f` or `-march=native` ? Is AVX-512F supported by CPU of machine where code was compiled?

Comment: Hi, just trying to find that. I built this locally on my own machine. It runs on one remote box, but gives this illegal instruction on a different remote box. This happens for both dynamic and static builds. We hardly use avx2, let alone avx512. The code has not been changed. Its something to do with gcc/os/kernel version I think.

Comment: avx512 is not supported on the CPU of the machine which built the code